# Linking to and downloading a file where name changes? Best method, Regex?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing some html that links to a server to download a file.  The location always remains the same, however, the file name gets updated.

Basically the link is like this:

http://www.somedomain.com/somedir/dir/filename_revA.pdf

The filename will often get revised ("filename_revB.pdf") for example.  My goal would not having to change the html href code each time this happens.

**TL;DR-- I want to be able to reference an url, ie: 'http://www.somedomain.com/somedir/dir/' 
but not need the filename to fetch the file that is there after the last /.**

Would RegEx (javascript) be best solution or a better method?  Sorry if it's been asked I tried searching couldn't quite get what I wanted- requesting a URL WITHOUT the filename needed-while still fetching the actual file that's there.  There's only one file that is there at all times, but perhaps to be safer using part of the name since only the last part changes?

edit- I don't have access to the server that hosts the file(s).

Comment: *"RedEx"* - ...regex?

Comment: It would be better and way easier to handle this kind of thing server-side (remap the request to point to the most recent version of the file you're trying to serve).

Comment: Fixed to Regex.  I don't have access to the server that hosts the file.

Comment: If you're lucky, [directory listing](http://www.internetblog.org.uk/post/551/what-is-directory-listing/) is available on the server. Then you could just sort the list of files and get the one you want.